# Ignore @Transient fields of an entity automatically during json serialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using hibernate for entity persistance in application along with spring mvc I have a multiple @Transient fields in an entity in a application is there a way to tell Json parser to automatically ignore all @Transient annotated fields in entity without the need to use @JsonIgnore or @JsonIgnoreProperties

Comment: `@Transient` is to indicate the field is not persistent. `@JsonIgnore` is to indicate the field is to be ignored by the serialization/deserialization processor, they have very different meanings.

Comment: i know that but I am asking for a way to ignore all transient fields automatically without adding @JsonIgnore to the fileds

Comment: Why don't you want to user @JsonIgnore? Is there a solid reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

`@Transient` is to indicate the field is not persistent. `@JsonIgnore` is to indicate the field is to be ignored by the serialization/deserialization processor, they have very different meanings.

One option is have Json processor base serial/deserialization from available fields (vs getter/setters), then mark your @Transient fields with additional `transient` keyword. If you have getters/setters, you'll also need to add appropriate visibility rules. For example, this will serialize all fields not marked with `transient`.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility=Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

Comment: i tried this but this hides everything except transient field

Comment: sorry was interrupted, as I was re-writing answer. I forgot to include fieldVisibility=Visibility.ANY

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better way instead of using @jsonignore to the fields in an entity 
on child class use JsonBackreference and on parent use JsonManagedReference
[For more information go through this blog post](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.in/2010/10/json-jackson-to-rescue.html)